# how to redirect page on submit with Dropzone.js and Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

I'm using Rails 4, with [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). I have a form where users fill in everything and can upload a photo and than submit the form without having Dropzone upload it automatically. So, with the following js It will "put it on hold" until I click the submit button.

> items/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@item, html: {class: 'form-horizontal form dropzone', multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <%= token_tag(nil) %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'img-input', accept: 'image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg', multiple: false %>
    <%= f.submit 'Done', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block item-submit' %>
<% end %>
```

> items.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", {
    maxFiles: 1, 
    maxFilesize: 1, 
    paramName: "item[image]",
    addRemoveLinks: true, 
    clickable:'#dropzonePreview',
    previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
    thumbnailWidth: 300,
    thumbnailHeight: 300,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false
  });

  $(".item-submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
      dropzone.processQueue();
    }
  );

});
```

> Routes

```
resources :items
```

> ItemsController

```
  def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)

    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item, notice: "item was successfully created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The issue I'm having is that I can create a new item and drag n drop a photo but after I submit the form, instead of redirecting to items/show, it will remain on the same page and render the error:

> EDITED

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 15:19:36 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>............  

  [1m[35m (11.6ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[33mItem Store (45.9ms)[0m  {"id":16}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/items/16
Completed 302 Found in 2153ms (Searchkick: 45.9ms | ActiveRecord: 13.8ms)


Started GET "/items/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 15:19:38 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
  [1m[36mItem Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 16]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/user/dummyappone/app/views"
```

How can I make it so when my form is submitted, it goes to the show page and still allows the displaying of a flash message and errors if not saved?

Comment: Can you post your log file, just the snippet where it calls `create` after submitting the form?

Comment: @trh Yep, check the edit now.

Comment: You're not redirecting because you're response is in json (as you can see from your log file it was processed in json, instead of html).  You can create a success js callback in your form  and do a window.location call.

Comment: @trh Not really sure how that's done. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments: just add this to your js:

```
dropzone.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
  window.location.href = ("/items/"+responseText.id)
});
```

This assumes that `dropzone` is the dropzone you initialized in your previous JS

Comment: Thing about this way is what about rails errors and a flash message? It seems like this goes outside of the rails controller because I'm trying everything to still stay in the controller action. I should have been more specific about what I wanted. This solves 1/3 of the issue. I'm really trying to mimic the rails defaults when creating a resource.

Comment: Well you WILL get a flash error, because you added the errors in the controller.  As for the rest, I don't understand what you need.  There is a limit to how mimic-ed you can be when you're breaking conventions.  But do please update your question or a create a new one that carefuly outlines what you need.  Best of luck